# Force validation after EntityManager.remove()

Tags: java, jpa

I have a `remove()` in my DAO class and sometimes I got error because

> FOREING KEY violation

. I.E: When user try to remove a Product that is used by a Customer.

This is my remove() method:

```
public void delete(AbstractEntity entidade) throws DAOException {
        try {          
            entidade = getEm().merge(entidade);
            getEm().remove(entidade);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
            throw new DAOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The problem is that error just appear when database touched. I need to validate some exceptions in this point to send a right Exception to USER, like: **"You can delete this because other information is using it."**

Comment: I need make some generic to affect everybody. A lot of projects use DAO class.

Comment: then do it at the service layer, if it is a constraint, you need to validate the inputs/action before you execute it.  That'd be my approach (since not all entities have the same constraints)

Comment: In fact, i want to catch the SQLException and check if a VAlidationContrainst, i think this is better, but any exception occurrs in getEm().remove()

Comment: IMHO, that's a poor choice of design - I would not do it that way.  I would validate ahead of time and handle the error message beforehand - you know already what the exception is likely to be, leave the `try/catch` for the unknown cases.  I would not recommend it